# CMake how to remove the default /usr/lib path when linking a shared library?

Tags: c++11, cmake, dynamic-linking, std

This is the current output from the otool -L libtarget.dylib

`libA.dylib`
`libB.dylib`
`/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)`
`/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)`

I was able to remove the `libc++.dylib` dependence, but I cannot figure out how to remove `libSystem.dylib`.

Is there a way to remove the default `/usr/lib` path when linking to a shared library in CMake?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It will help if you show us how you are linking to these libraries. Try to create a minimal example that reproduce your problem, then post your `CMakeLists.txt`. so we can clearly see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Within my CMakeLists.txt I do something similar to the following: `target_link_libraries(target A)`
`target_link_libraries(target libB)`
The library currently builds correctly. However, what I am trying to do is remove the dependency on both the `libc++.dylib` and the `libSystem.dylib`. Let me know if you have any suggestions @thomas_f

Comment: @Alpha234 do you mean you want to get rid of the hard-coded path? If your executable is linked to the standard C++ libs, it probably means it depends on it and hence it is not possible to 'get rid of it'?

Comment: @Nibor I'm very new to CMake, but I don't think that it is a hard-coded path, as I was able to remove the `libc++.dylib` dependency. The lib that I am building cannot have standard lib dependencies, or it will not load properly. I believe that the linking to `libSystem.dylib` is just a default in CMake and I would like to know how to remove that dependency.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how did you 'remove' the dependency?

Comment: @Nibor I did the following to remove the default linking to libc++:
`set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_LIBRARIES "")    
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "")    
set_target_properties(yourtarget PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)`

Answer (score 0):

That is gonna be difficult, even the most simple C example links to `libSystem.B` For instance, if you execute

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc -
```

followed by

```
otool -L a.out
```

it will show you dependency on `libSystem.B`

```
a.out:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
```

An alternative is to use `rpath`:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib @rpath/libSystem.B.dylib a.out
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but my goal is to entirely avoid linking the `libSystem.dylib` to my shared library, not change the path of the `libSystem.dylib`. I've been attempting to solve the problem by modifying the `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` by adding the `-nostdlib` flag, but have been unsuccessful so far. @Nibor

Comment: The main point of the answer was to show that even a trivial example not using _any_ of the standard library facilities has a dependency on it